# Internationalization in Liferay 6.2 Alloy UI

Tags: internationalization, liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

we are developing a site in which we have to use internationalization concept for describing the web in different languages(18). I already translate my labels of text box and etc but I am fail to translate the label of buttons and also we have one navigation bar in which seven different pages links are present. How to change this navigation links.[image]

Here how to translate these into different languages. I am using Liferay 6.2 Alloy UI.
Thanks and regards 
asif aftab

Comment: can you provide your code looks like?

Comment: http://liferayasif.blogspot.in/2013/12/internationalizationi18n-in-liferay-61.html

Comment: In my blog I post the complete program. In this labels and titles are changes but navigation value is not changing and button value and I am not how to do this. I am using AUI and now Liferay 6.2. Thanks for your help . asif aftab

Answer (score 4):

Liferay provides a built in internationalization integration with Alloy UI.So for Internationalization  in `<aui>` tag you simply have to do :

```
<aui:input name="helloWorld" value="anyThing"/>
```

And it automatically internationalize `name` field of `<aui>` tag converting it as **Hello World** `<label>`.And if you want to provide custom  for  tag you need to use

```
<aui:input name="helloWorld" value="anyThing" label="edit-button"/>
```

and define `edit-button` in **Language.properties**.

However for normal `<html>` tag this method doesn't work.And I assume that your are using `<a>` tag for your navigation. For providing internationalization in such tag liferay has provided a method.

```
<liferay-ui:message key="title-home-navigation"/>
```

and define the **`key`** in **Language.properties.**

So you could use it like :

```
<h1><liferay-ui:message key="title-manage-organization"/></h1>
<a href="${homeButton}" ><liferay-ui:message key="title-home-navigation"/></a>
```

for achieving internationalization feature in such tags.

I hope this help your cause.

Comment: Thanks, and it is really helpful.